# Using list elements to create .format() mapping for .json() object?

Tags: python, json, list, string.format

I have the following object being returned using `response.json` within the `Requests module`:

```
{u'statColumns': [u'apps', u'subOn', u'minsPlayed', u'tackleWonTotal', u'challengeLost', 
u'tackleTotalAttempted'], u'paging': {u'firstRecordIndex': 1, u'resultsPerPage': 1,     u'lastRecordIndex':
1, u'totalPages': 431, u'currentPage': 1, u'totalResults': 431}, u'playerTableStats': 
[{u'positionText': u'Defender', u'rating': 8.37, u'weight': 77, u'playerId': 22079, u'height': 188, 
u'teamId': 32, u'playedPositions': u'-DC-', u'challengeLost': 0.0, u'isManOfTheMatch': False, u'isOpta':
True, u'subOn': 0, u'tackleWonTotal': 2.0, u'tournamentShortName': u'EPL', u'apps': 1, u'teamName':
u'Manchester United', u'tournamentRegionId': 252, u'regionCode': u'gb-nir', u'tournamentRegionCode':
u'gb-eng', u'playedPositionsShort': u'D(C)', u'seasonId': 4311, u'ranking': 1, u'minsPlayed': 90, 
u'tournamentName': u'Premier League', u'isActive': True, u'name': u'Jonny Evans', u'firstName': 
u'Jonny', u'lastName': u'Evans', u'age': 26, u'seasonName': u'2014/2015', u'tournamentId': 2,
u'tackleTotalAttempted': 2.0}]}
```

This object has two elements, `playerTableStats` and `statColumns`. These can accessed with the following code:

```
playerTableStats = response[u'playerTableStats']
statColumns = response[u'statColumns']
```

If I convert the contents of `statColumns` into a string object, I can use it as part of a `.format()` statement to map `playerTableStats`. I could do this like so:

```
var1 = ['one','two','three','four']
var1 = 'u"{',var1[0],'}','{',var1[1],'}','{',var1[2],'}','{',var1[3],'}"'
var1 = ''.join(var1)

var2 = (var1.format(**responser))

print var2
```

However that doesn't seem very Pythonic and doesn't take into account the fact that both `statColumns` and `playerTableStats` will vary in their number of elements when I am returning different .json objects from the same site.

Is there a cleaner way to get all elements of `statColumns` into the format:

```
u"{one}{two}{three}{four}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
var2 = ''.join('{' + x + '}' for x in var1)
```

Comment: @falsetru...ok that worked great, thanks. could you explain what you mean by a generator expression though please?

Comment: @gdogg371, Generator expression is similar to list comprehension, except it results in generator instead of list. I added a link to the Python tutorial page for generator expression. Follow the link for more detail.

Comment: @gdogg371, If you are not clear, try the following list comprehension: `['{' + x + '}' for x in var1]`. You will get a list of `['one', 'two', ...]`. If you use generator expression, it will return a generator which yields each element lazily.